# Python list of a list of objects

Tags: python, list, class, object, attributeerror

I have the following code in Module1:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ele1 = None
        self.ele2 = None 

def collect():
    return getdata()

def getdata():
    data1 = []
    data2 = []
    data3 = []

    testObj = Test()
    testObj.ele1 = 'Stack'
    testObj.ele2 = 'Overflow'

    data1.append(testObj)

    return [data1, data2, data3]
```

Then in another module, I have the following code:

```
import Module1

mydata = Module1.collect()

for entry in mydata:
    if len(entry) > 0:
        for subentry in entry:
            print subentry.ele1
            print subentry.ele2
```

When printing subentry.ele1 or subentry.ele2, I get the following error:

```
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ele1'
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: i think you are not showing us the code that causes the problem

Comment: I don't see `'name'` anywhere in your code

Comment: Its right there defined as a function inside Module1.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno what I was looking at;   https://repl.it/Ghdl/0 - your code as written, works, except I don't think I can put modules on repl.it, but that suggests your module import isn't importing the right code, or there's a typo somewhere.

Comment: Yes, the same works for me too, when I have everything under one module, but doesn't when I have two different modules as shown above.

Comment: Are you doing anything odd with your interpreter sessions (like editing the code and not restarting the interpreter)? Do you have a stale `Module1.pyo` file? I can't think of much else that could explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @Blckknght I have deleted the generated pyc files, but same result.